# Can I covert paths to brush strokes in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to create shapes using the shape tool, but then change the stroke to a line that looks hand drawn, or lay down a brush stroke that follows the same path -- by some method other than tracing with a mouse (I have no stylus). Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

To apply a brush to the path, simply click the brush you want to use in the Brush Panel.

You can also apply a width profile if using CS5 or CS6 via the Stroke Panel or Control bar.

You can also use the Width Tool (CS5 and CS6) to apply custom width variations to any stroked path.